# xml-api jar issue in wildfly - module loading precedence

Tags: wildfly

I am creating global module in wildfly which includes xml-api jar as well.
But When the parsing happens for the xml file, it throws the following exception.

I searched in the forum and many post saying to remove the xml-api and xml-beans jars from the class path.  Because there is a conflict of JBoss / JDK xml jars and our xml-api jars.  But I need to have my jars to be loaded with precedence.  How can I achieve that.  Please provide the suggestion.

```
13:11:51,686 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastExcep
tion: __redirected.__DatatypeFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.datatype.Dataty
peFactory
13:11:51,688 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFa
ctory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
13:11:51,690 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.conv
erters.extended.DurationConverter$1.getFactory(DurationConverter.java:39)
13:11:51,691 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.conv
erters.extended.DurationConverter.<init>(DurationConverter.java:44)
13:11:51,691 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    ... 74 more
```

Thanks
Senthil

Comment: Jars named `xml-apis.jar` are responsible for more build and/or runtime problems than all the rest put together. Just get rid of it. These API's and implementation are provided by your JDK

Comment: If I remove the xml-api.jar then it results NoSuchClass Error "org.xml.SaxException".  This class is in xml-api.jar.

Comment: It will help if you describe how you're parsing your XML. For most use cases the JDK provides all the APIs that you need. [org.xml.SaxException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXException.html) is part of the JDK, so this will be a bug in your module definition.

Comment: Actually I am trying to deploy the drools jars in wildfly 10.  My application is having kmodule.xml which is parsed by drools lib.  My code doesn't parse the xml.  If I put the all the libs in WEB-INF/lib folder it is working perfectly.  But if I declare global module it is not working.

Comment: What version of drools are you using?

Comment: Please add your `module.xml` file to your question.

Comment: I am using drools 6.5.0 version

Comment: I have added the corrected module.xml in the answer section

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.
I have removed the below modules and added javax.api and org.slf4j as dependencies in my module.xml.  It is because wildfly already having these modules and loaded as part of core class loading.  Thats why there is a conflict when it is reloaded.

### Module.xml

### Removed content :

```
<resource-root path="xml-apis-<version>.jar">
<resource-root path="slf4j-api-<version>.jar"/>
```

### Added content :

```
<dependencies>
         <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
  </dependencies>
```

### corrected Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="drools">
    <resources>

        <resource-root path="aether-api-1.0.0.v20140518.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aether-connector-basic-1.0.0.v20140518.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aether-impl-1.0.0.v20140518.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aether-spi-1.0.0.v20140518.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aether-transport-file-1.0.0.v20140518.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aether-transport-http-1.0.0.v20140518.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aether-transport-wagon-1.0.0.v20140518.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="ant-1.8.3.jar"/>
         <resource-root path="ant-launcher-1.8.3.jar" />   
         <resource-root path="antlr-runtime-3.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="cdi-api-1.0-SP4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-codec-1.4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="drools-beliefs-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>

        <resource-root path="drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="drools-core-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="drools-decisiontables-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="drools-jsr94-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="drools-pmml-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="drools-reteoo-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="drools-scorecards-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="drools-verifier-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="drools-templates-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>

        <resource-root path="ecj-4.4.2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="guava-13.0.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="httpclient-4.3.6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="httpcore-4.3.3.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="itext-2.1.2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="javax.inject-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar"/>
                <resource-root path="jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jsoup-1.8.3.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jsr94-1.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jsr250-api-1.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="kie-api-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
                <resource-root path="kie-ci-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="kie-internal-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>
                                <resource-root path="knowledge-api-6.5.0.Final.jar"/>

        <resource-root path="maven-aether-provider-3.2.5.jar"/>
         <resource-root path="maven-artifact-3.2.5.jar" />   
    <resource-root path="maven-compat-3.2.5.jar"/> 
        <resource-root path="maven-core-3.2.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="maven-model-3.2.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="maven-plugin-api-3.2.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="maven-repository-metadata-3.2.5.jar"/>

        <resource-root path="maven-settings-3.2.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="maven-settings-builder-3.2.5.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="mvel2-2.2.8.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.0.M1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.0.M1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="plexus-cipher-1.7.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar"/> 
         <resource-root path="plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="poi-3.13.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="poi-ooxml-3.13.jar"/>  
        <resource-root path="poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="protobuf-java-2.6.0.jar"/>

        <resource-root path="sisu-guice-3.2.3-no_aop.jar"/>
    <!--    <resource-root path="slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar"/>  -->
        <resource-root path="stax-api-1.0.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="wagon-http-2.6.jar"/>
         <resource-root path="wagon-http-shared-2.6.jar"/> 
        <resource-root path="wagon-provider-api-2.6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar"/>
         <resource-root path="xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar"/> 
        <resource-root path="xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="xstream-1.4.9.jar"/>
    </resources>
 <dependencies>

        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>

  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Thanks

Senthil

Comment: Yep - that's the path I was heading down. You can improve this further I think by removing `cdi-api-1.0-SP4.jar`, `jaxb-*-2.2.11.jar`, `jsr250-api-1.0.jar` and `stax-api-1.0.1.jar`.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I will try your suggestion.